# Side captions for tables in svjour3.cls

Tags: captions

Springer's `svjour3.cls` provides a `\sidecaption` command that works fine for figures but not for tables. See the MWE below: the table and the caption are not aligned.
Is there a fix?

```
\documentclass[]{svjour3}
\def\LIPSUM{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.}
\begin{document}
\LIPSUM
\par
\begin{table}[h]\sidecaption
\begin{tabular}{l|rrrrrrr}
$k$ & $m$\quad
        1  & 2   & 3   & 4   & 5  & 6  & total \\
\hline\rule{0pt}{2.4ex}%
1     & 11 &     &     &     &    &    &   10    \\
2     & 0  & 20  &     &     &    &    &   20    \\
3     & 0  & 22  & 39  &     &    &    &   61    \\
4     & 0  & 33  & 85  & 33  &    &    &   151   \\
5     & 0  & 74  & 149 & 94  & 15 &    &   332   \\
6     & 0  & 100 & 284 & 187 & 92 & 10 &   673   \\
% 7     & ?  & ?   & ?   & ?   & ?  & ?  & 7 & ?
\end{tabular}
\caption{\LIPSUM}
\end{table}
\par
\LIPSUM
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is trivial: align the table at the bottom:

```
\begin{tabular}[b]{l|rrrrrr|r}
```

[image]